# ¿Por qué mi método no deshabilita los componentes del JPanel?

Tags: java

En mi proyecto tengo dos clases que generan Paneles. Estoy utilizando Herencia:

La clase padre se llama `GodPanel`

```
package Trivia.Secciones;

import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class GodPanel extends JPanel {
    private boolean end;
    private int i;
    private String paneles[], seccion[];

    public GodPanel(){
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setLayout(new CardLayout());
        end = false;                  
    }

    public void showCard(String val){
        CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)this.getLayout();
        cl.show(this, val);
    }

    public void addCard(Component obj,String name){add(obj,name);}
    public void removeAll(String[] name){removeAll();}

    public void inicializarPaneles(String[] obj){
        paneles = null;
        paneles = obj;
    }

    public void inicializarSecciones(String[] obj){
        seccion = null;
        seccion = obj;
    }

    public JPanel createSlide(String url) throws IOException{
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new MigLayout()){
        Image image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream(url));
        @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
            }
        };
        panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(965,600));
        return panel;
    }

    public Component getBasicComponents(int op){
        switch (op) {
            case 1:
                JButton Bnext = new JButton(">>>");
                Bnext.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,20));
                Bnext.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                        if(i != paneles.length - 1){
                        i++;
                        showCard(paneles[i]);
                        if(i == paneles.length - 1){
                            end = true;
                        }
                      }
                    }
                });
                return Bnext;
            case 2:
                JButton Bant = new JButton("<<<");
                Bant.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,20));
                Bant.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                        if(i != 0){
                            i--;     
                            showCard(paneles[i]);
                        }
                    }
                });
                return Bant;
            case 3:
                JComboBox secciones = new JComboBox();
                secciones.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(515,28));
                for(String sec: seccion){secciones.addItem(sec);}
                return secciones;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return null;
    }

     public void enableComponents(Container container, boolean enable, int option) {
        Component[] components = container.getComponents();
        for (Component component : components) {
            switch(option){
                case 1:
                component.setEnabled(enable);
                break;
                case 2:
                component.setVisible(enable);
                break;
            }
            if (component instanceof Container) {
                enableComponents((Container)component, enable, option);
            }
        }
    }

    public void setPanelInicial(){showCard(paneles[0]); i=0;}
    public void setEnd(boolean v){end = v;}
    public boolean getEnd(){return end;}   
}
```

Y esta es una clase hija llamada `Nivel3`

```
package Trivia.Secciones;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Nivel3 extends GodPanel{
    private String[] nombres = {"A1","P2"};
    private JPanel[] paneles;
    private String[] sec = {"Centros Educativos","Situación Estructural y Equipamento de Planes",
    "Cantidad de Estudiantes por Niveles","Cantidad de Educadores por Niveles y Relacion Alumno/Educador",
    "Centros de Promocion Cultural","Grupos Culturales Representativos",
    "Instalaciones Deportivas y Condiciones"};

    public Nivel3() throws IOException{
        paneles = new JPanel[2];
        inicializarPaneles(nombres);
        inicializarSecciones(sec);
        for(int i=0;i<paneles.length-1;i++){
            paneles[i] = createSlide("/assets/FondoEdu.png");
            paneles[i].add(getBasicComponents(2), "split 4");
            paneles[i].add(getBasicComponents(1),"gapleft 10");
            paneles[i].add(new JLabel("Acceso Rapido: "),"gapleft 200");
            paneles[i].add(getBasicComponents(3),"wrap 20");
            if(i == (paneles.length - 1)){
                enableComponents(paneles[i],false,1);
            }
            for(String names: nombres){
                add(paneles[i],names);
            }
        }       
    }  
}
```

Ok, mi "problema" (lo coloco en comillas, porque el método funciona bien) esta en el método `enableComponents`. En la clase hija notan que creo paneles mediante loops `for`. Pues bien, estoy intentando que siempre el último panel tenga TODOS los componentes deshabilitados. Inserté una condición que, por razones que desconozco, no quiere andar:

```
if(i == (paneles.length - 1)) {
    enableComponents(paneles[i],false,1);
}
```

¿Me darían ideas de cómo deshabilitar todo solamente en el último panel si es que esto no tiene arreglo?

Comment: Dices que el método funciona pero que no hace lo que debería. Eso significa que el método no funciona...

Comment: El metodo no tenia nada, quiza no me explique bien o no me capto.. el problema era mis ciclos for, porque ahora si me deshabilita todos los componentes del ultimo panel de mi array. En mi respuesta explico a fondo lo que ocurria... @LuiggiMendoza

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El verdadero problema de todo... era la misma declaracion del ciclo for (especialmente en la condicion del ciclo):

1) Hice un array de JPanels mas grande en esta prueba.

```
paneles = new JPanel[4];
```

2) Al utilizar la funcion `.length` me devolvia como es de esperarse, el numero 4. Como ya se conoce, los arrays van del 0 en adelante... por lo que mi "numero 4" seria el 3.

El ciclo for como lo escribi inicialmente contaba hasta 2, ya que la condicion dice "Corre el ciclo mientras que la variable contadora ( i ) sea **menor** que 3":

```
 for(int i=0;i<paneles.length-1;i++){ // Esto contaba 0 1 2
        paneles[i] = createSlide("/assets/FondoEdu.png");
        paneles[i].add(getBasicComponents(2), "split 4");
        paneles[i].add(getBasicComponents(1),"gapleft 10");
        paneles[i].add(new JLabel("Acceso Rapido: "),"gapleft 200");
        paneles[i].add(getBasicComponents(3),"wrap 20");
        if(i == (paneles.length - 1)){
            enableComponents(paneles[i],false,1);
        }
        for(String names: nombres){
            add(paneles[i],names);
        }
    }
```

Lo unico que debia yo hacer, simplemente era añadirle un igual a la condicion (<=) o quitarle el - 1 a la condicion... ya las cosas cambian, ahora le dice al ciclo for "Corre el ciclo mientras que la variable contadora ( i ) sea menor que **4**":

```
 for(int i=0;i<paneles.length;i++)//Ahora si vas a llegar hasta 3!
```

Y ahora si agarra la condicion:

```
if(i == (paneles.length - 1)){
        enableComponents(paneles[i],false,1);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

A primera vista el código se ve bien, aun que llamar `setEnabled(false)` en un `Container` no tiene ningún efecto mas que garantizar que `getEnabled()` resulta en `false`, si me recuerdo bien.

Trata lo siguiente:

```
 public void enableComponents(Container container, boolean enable, int option) {
    Component[] components = container.getComponents();
    for (Component component : components) {
        switch(option){
            case 1:
            component.setEnabled(enable);
            break;
            case 2:
            component.setVisible(enable);
            break;
            System.out.println(String
               .format("enableComponents: %s (%s) enable:%b vis: %b"
               , component.getClass().getSimpleName(),
               , (component instanceof JButton) ? component.getText() : component.getName()
               , component.getEnabled(), component.getVisible()));
        }
        if (component instanceof Container) {
            enableComponents((Container)component, enable, option);
        }
    }
```

Comment: He probado insertando el trozo de codigo que tienes ahi a mi metodo, pero al parecer tiene errores... igualmente agradezco muchisimo tu ayuda! ya pude solucionarlo al final...

Comment: Entonces agrega tu solución a tu respuesta o mejor responde a ti mismo con la respuesta. ;) Así los que vienen en el futuro pueden disfrutarlo. Si, tuvo, un error tipográfico, faltaba un cierre de paréntesis. Esta editado.